# Is there any way we can read views created in Athena from glue job using pyspark?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue, amazon-athena

We are trying to read data from view created in Athena from glue job using below code-

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
athena_view_dataframe = (
    glueContext.read.format("jdbc")
    .option("driver", "com.simba.athena.jdbc.Driver")
    .option("AwsCredentialsProviderClass",
            "com.simba.athena.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider")
    .option("url", "jdbc:awsathena://athena.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:443")
    .option("dbtable", "<db_name>.<table_name>")
    .option("S3OutputLocation", "s3://<bucket_name>/<folder_name>/")
    .load()
)
job.commit()
```

But we are below error-

```
java.sql.SQLException: [JDBC Driver]Exception parsing query SELECT * FROM <db_name>.<table_name> WHERE 1=0 (Service: AmazonAthena; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRequestException; Request ID: af390fb5-3608-488d-8575-3ad4beefc985; Proxy: null)
```

Here we by default **where 1=0** is appending the query.

Can someone help how we can resolve this and pull data from Athena view?